# ReactJS - How to change style and class of react component?

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs

I'd like to be able to change the `style` and `className` of a component before it's rendered, outside of it's render function. I've got more going on than I'm showing here, but this is the basic idea, being able to set the style and className as properties somehow:

The following works only if the "style" variable is moved inside the render function, and added to the div like normal (e.g. `<div style={style}>` ). How can I make the following work?

[JS Fiddle that doesnt work](http://jsfiddle.net/Qr6y9/1/)

EDIT: [Working JS Fiddle here !](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldphmc9h/)

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var Main = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
       var result = this.doRender();

       var style = {
         border:'1px solid red'
       };

       result.style = style;

       return result;
    },

    doRender: function() {
        return (
          <div>Test</div>
        );
    }
});

React.renderComponent(<Main/>, document.body);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

React elements are designed to be immutable; usually your app will be easiest to understand if you restructure it to build the proper props upfront instead of mutating them later, and React assumes that this is the case. That said, you can use [React.cloneElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement) to get the effect you want:

```
render: function() {
    return React.cloneElement(this.doRender(), {
        style: {border: '1px solid red'}
    });
},
```

(Note that if your `doRender()` function returned a custom component then changing the props would change that component's props, not the underlying DOM component that gets produced. There's no way to render it down to a DOM component and change that component's props, short of manually mutating the DOM in `componentDidMount`.)

Comment: thanks for the pointers! here's [an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qr6y9/2/) that uses the above and works...

Comment: Could you possibly explain a bit more why you think this approach is `mutating the props`? I don't change my properties at any time during the lifetime of the component - i just want to avoid having to write `<div className={classes} style={styles}>` every time I write a component that can have custom css styling and classes. I'd like to have functions that are specifically for this purpose, eg `getClasses` and `getStyles`, which are then applied automatically to my component without having to make the actual markup uglier, and duplicate `className={classes} style={styles}>` all the time. Thx!

Comment: It might make sense to make a `Box` component that renders `<div style={{'border': '1px solid red'}}>{this.props.children}</div>` and then use `<Box>Test</Box>` instead in your component's render function.

Comment: thanks for the feedback! my real intent with this is to have a mixin that can manage my render process... I'd like all my components to be able to implement a series of custom properties, for simplifying managing style and class oriented things (e.g. height, align, frame, etc), and a mixin approach seems to work fine for what I'm doing, as implemented above, but requires that I put the `style={styles}`, `className={classes}`, and a call to a method `getClassesAndStylesForWrapperProperties` at the top of each components render method. Which is alot of duplicate code in each component.

Comment: React values explicitness over magic. Having mixins that change how render works makes your code harder to reason about. That said, it's possible that what you want will be more practical in a future version of React but I can't say for sure.

Comment: I'll probably just be explicit as opposed to doing the cloning, as I don't expect to be doing anything more than what I've already suggested... thanks again....

Comment: Created a issue on react here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3237 . I agree that this should be done automatically as apart of render. Adding a className or style to a component should automatically append to the top level dom element.

Comment: @BenAlpert Would it make sense to update this answer to recommend using `React.cloneElement` rather than `React.cloneWithProps`? Losing the `key` and `ref` from the original component is unlikely to be desired behavior.

Answer (score -5):

you can try this game

```
componentDidMount() {
  document.querySelector('.yourClassName').style = 'your: style'
}
```