# Changing class and style of React children using cloneElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using the latest React (0.13) I am attempting to change the class and style of a child element using `cloneElement` prior to rendering.

Looking through the tests: [https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0.13-stable/src/classic/element/**tests**/ReactElementClone-test.js#L44](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0.13-stable/src/classic/element/__tests__/ReactElementClone-test.js#L44)

And other answers: [ReactJS - How to change style and class of react component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856044/reactjs-how-to-change-style-and-class-of-react-component/24856195#24856195)

It seems like this should be pretty straightforward, however I can't seem to achieve the desired behavior as detailed in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/7924/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'className' prop you are sending is being sent to the `Child` component, not the `div`, so 'green' never reaches the `div`.

```
<Parent>
  <div>
    <Child className="green">
      <div className="red">#textnode</div>
    </Child>
    <Child className="green">
      <div className="red">#textnode</div>
    </Child>
  </div>
</Parent>
```

Here's an updated fiddle to show you what's going on: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/7927/

Here's a jsfiddle that might help clarify it more: http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/7926/

This is probably what you intended: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/7928/
Note the `{...this.props}` to transfer `Child`'s props to the `div`.

Comment: Thank you, that seems quite obvious now. What if you didn't have control of the child component's markup or render function though? Perhaps you're using a hypothetical component library that you don't want to modify?

Comment: I think it is discouraged to mutate components or any kind of monkey patching of components.  Best practice is to have "pure" render functions that given the same props and state always output the same thing.

Comment: That would also cause tight coupling between components.  Generally, React will try to stop you from doing things like that.

Comment: As a side note, React does not support passing style properties this way, see  https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2231